# Cannot remove Main Interface from Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am working on an iPad app that does not use a .storyboard interface. My AppDelegate has the following code (in Xcode 8.2.1):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = MyViewController()
    return true
}
```

I've cleared the Main Interface field from the target as shown below:
[image]

However, upon running the app, I receive the following crash message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard
>   named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle

It seems that upon Building/Running the app, the Main Interface field is automatically repopulated with "Main". I've been able to remove this on universal apps, but this is my first, and unsuccessful attempt with an iPad only project. I've tried both pressing Return on the keyboard and clicking outside the field in hopes of saving my Main Interface text field changes, but still have the same result.

My question is: How can I remove the Main Interface from the target and thus avoid this error message?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check your `Info.plist`. There should be an entry for the **Main storyboard file base name**. Delete it there and you should be good to go!

Comment: @MyBikeIsAwesome Always mark answer correct if you find it useful.

Comment: @TusharSharma. I cannot mark it because it was answered less than 8 minutes ago.

Comment: What if I want to change the storyboard dynamically?

Comment: @chandru I'm not sure what you mean in the context of this thread.

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for your response. Well, Consider. I am having two storyboards Login and Home. One time login scenario. I have to display home storyboard contents if the user have looged in and login storyboard content if he hasn't logged in.

Comment: In that case you leave the **Main storyboard file base name** empty. Instead you add logic (is logged in / is not logged in) to your `AppDelegate` / `SceneDelegate` (or wherever) and set the root view controller in code.